# How to access MySQL Python Connector with Python 2.7.8 and Sublime Text 3 on OS X 10.9

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sublimetext3, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to set up MySQL to work with python 2.7.8 and Sublime Text 3 on OS X 10.9, so I installed the MySQL python connector. Whenever I try to run "import mysql.connector", I get back "ImportError: No module named connector".

**How should this be configured so that I can use the connector to access MySQL?**

Details:

-Sublime is installed under Applications

-Sublime Text 3 uses python 3 as the default, so I had to set up a python 2.7 build system. Here is my code for this system:

```
  "cmd": ["/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python2"
```

-Python is installed at

```
 /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

-MySQL executable is installed at

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.6.19-osx10.7-x86_64/bin
```

-The connector has a symlink at

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector
```

and is installed fully at

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector
```

Additionally, I added the following to .bash_profile to get the necessary directories added to the path.

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# trying to get mysql access
PATH = "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but this is my first time setting this much up, and I've spent way too many hours googling and trying to find out what I'm doing wrong. Anyone have an idea what I need to change to access the connector module? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't use the shell `$PATH` variable to locate importable modules, it uses a list called `sys.path` in Python. If you run your interpreter and print out `sys.path` from it you should see that the `site-packages` directory is already being searched. You can request further directories be added to `sys.path` before program execution by adding them to the `$PYTHONPATH` shell environment variable.

It appears from the structure that `mysql` is a package with `connector` being a sub-package, and I am guessing that you need to make the symbolic link one directory higher (*i.e.* to the `mysql` directory) to pick up the necessary `__init__.py` that will cause it to be recognized as a package.

In general it's a good idea to learn to use `pip` to install modules and packages in so-called virtual environments. it allows you (for example) to have different programs use different versions of the same module.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Understanding sys.path helped a lot. The issue was the filename I was using to test everything was named mysql.py, and its parent directory was in sys.path, it was trying to import this file instead of the mysql directory. I just renamed the file, and it found the right directory. Thanks again for the assistance!

Comment: :-) Glad you can move forward!

Comment: I too was using program filename mysql.py which was creating conflict and overwriting default behaviour. Changed it to mysqlTest.py it works.